# Magento checkout components.phtml

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout

I am currently having an issue with my `Magento 2.1.8` checkout where the header is not displaying the logo, search bar, etc. correctly.

It is also showing an error in my `System.log` file

`[2018-03-08 10:25:31] main.CRITICAL: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'checkout_page_head_components' [] []`

I cannot find the specified template file anywhere. I have even downloaded all the magento core files from github and i cannot find the `components.phtml` file in there either.

does any one know where this file is located or how i access it?

thanks.

EDIT:

I have now found the file and it is identical the to the `components.phtml` file on github in the link below. This file has been unchanged so why would it say it is an "Invalid template file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can find your components.phtml file at below location,

[Github checkout link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/js/components.phtml)

You can find your components.phtml file from Checkout module.

Comment: I have now found this in my magento structure and it is the same as what is shown in the link you have sent me.

Why would mine be telling me it is Invalid?